# What is a one-parameter Newton's method?

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, parametric

The Newton's method that I know is defined as follows:

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

However, I've recently encountered [a paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/JAM/Volume2012/294086.pdf) that talks about a ***one-parameter family of Newton's method*** (page 4, equation 2.8), defined as follows:

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)-pf(x_n)}$$

What is this $p$ parameter in the equation above? Why is it not present in the first equation? What is this parameter useful for? What is that *one-parameter* Newton's method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the Newton method for the function $g(x)=e^{-px}f(x)$. Since $g'(x)=e^{-px}(f'(x)-pf(x))$, the iteration
$$
x_+=x-\frac{g(x)}{g'(x)}=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)-pf(x)}
$$
results. Note that the set of roots remains invariant, only the slopes change.

By using a complex value of $p=i\epsilon$ one can break the iteration away from the real axis in the case of polynomials with real coefficients and a real starting point.

I do not know if this trick is useful to "flatten" the function for faster convergence.